# Как правильно ограничить количество символов в сообщении?

Tags: javascript

```js
function truncate(str, maxlength){
 if(str.length > maxlength.length){
  alert(str.substr(0,3) + "...");
  // alert(a);
 }
 else{
  alert(str);
 };
};

truncate("громомпораженный", 'asasas');
```

Это правильно решение ? или можно улучшить ?

Comment: после `}` не нужно делать `;` - это только исключение, когда вы в переменной пишите анонимную или стрелочную функцию. так-как блок переменной должен завершиться `;`. В остальном - это избыточный код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы хотите как можно меньше кода, то держите:

```js
function truncate(str, maxlength){
  alert(str.length > maxlength.length ? str.substr(0,3) + "..." : str);
}

truncate("громомпораженный", 'asasas');
truncate("html", 'asasas');
```

Если же вы смотрите на это так , то читайте [тернарный оператор](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/%D0%A3%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80).

Comment: @xes `?` это `if`, `:`это `else`, ничего сложного. Ну а перед `?` условие `if`.

Comment: я и написал что это если грубо сказать замена условного оператора

Comment: @xes Ну да. :))

Comment: логичнее: alert(str.length > maxlength.length ? str.substr(0,maxlength-3) + "..." : str);

Comment: @sair ваш код неправильно работает.

Comment: да не заметил... имел ввиду alert(str.length > maxlength ? str.substr(0,maxlength-3) + "..." : str);